# Preview local html file in browser

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf, file-upload

I have web page where a user can upload files.
He can select which file to upload with `<t:inputFileUpload>` `jsf` tag.(This tag is like standard HTML input  tag with `type="file"`).

I want to add a preview feature.

when a user select a file (example:`html` file),  he could preview his html local file.

I know that there is a "problem" with the security restriction reasons of the browsers.

my first solution is to loading the file from the user local machine to the server, then making a link to that file on the server. The problem is that there is a risk on my server,
Maybe this file is corrupted...

Anybody have an idea and solution to this future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/zkaDA/) that shows a preview of `html` files. I created it from the tutorial found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

The most useful part of the code for you is the following

```
var f = // uploaded file.
var reader = new FileReader();
// Closure to capture the file information.
reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
         // Render the file.
         $("#preview").html(e.target.result);
    };
})(f);

// Read in the html file as text.
reader.readAsText(f);
```

This uses HTML5 `FileReader` to read and display the contents of the `html` file.

Comment: @lolo Just updated it to remove some unneeded and misleading code.

Comment: Where this page is loaded? If i want to load a css file that the html file will include it. there is any solution to that?

Comment: @lolo I have updated the JSFiddle to use an `iframe` to display each file's contents one after another. If you want to display styles from a `css` file you will need to determine that it is a `css` file and then add `<style>` tags around its content so that the `iframe` knows how to render it.

Comment: I know how html work with css files. but here i want to load 2 files: html file and css file. when i load them, the html file will preview with the css file..